# Почему в данном предложении необходима запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

**Но вот он завернул куда-то вбок, в мощеный переулок (,) и шаги его стихли**.

Comment: Когда Вы будете нормально оформлять шапку???

Comment: Вас какая именно запятая интересует?!

Answer (score 3):

***Но вот он завернул куда-то вбок,(1) в мощеный переулок,(2) и шаги его стихли.***

1)  Вторая запятая ставится в сложносочиненном предложении (ССП) с двумя основами: ***он завернул, шаги стихли.***

**Примечание**

Дискуссионным обычно является  вопрос об общем элементе (***но вот***) в начале ССП. Частица ***вот*** может быть общей, однако общим не считается союз ***НО***. Но в любом случае наличие обособленного обстоятельства в первом предложении не позволяет объединить их в одну фразу с помощью общего элемента.

2) Также запятыми 1 и 2 обособляется  обстоятельство ***в мощеный переулок*,** которое уточняет первое обстоятельство ***куда-то в бок*** с неопределенным значением.

3) Поэтому запятая 2 выполняет **две функции**: ставится на границе простых предложений в ССП и закрывает уточняющий оборот.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что в этом предложении вместо глагола "завернуть" лучше использовать глагол "свернуть". Наречие [**вбок**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA) имеет значение "в сторону", поэтому фраза "завернуть куда-то в сторону" мне кажется не совсем грамотной.

Завернул (куда?) куда-то вбок, (куда именно?) **в мощеный переулок** — это уточняющее словосочетание в значении обстоятельства места.

Я бы написала так:
*Но вот он **свернул** куда-то вбок, в мощеный переулок, и шаги его стихли.*

Вот предложение с уточнениями:
*В те же секунды «эстафет» завелся. С ревом мотора сорвался с места, пролетел по боковому карману, **свернул вбок, под кирпич, на улицу Байар,** понесся по встречке* (Ж.-П. Маншетт).

[Уточняющие члены предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)

Answer (score 1):

Уточняющий член предложения. Завернул (куда?) вбок, (куда именно?) в мощёный переулок.

UPD: Римма, спасибо большое.

Comment: **Вбок** (куда?) — наречие (= в сторону).

Comment: Тоже отметил это для себя при составлении ответа. По старому опыту всегда считал, что пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая в данном предложении необходима на основании **уточняющего оборота**, относящемуся к сочетанию "куда-то вбок". Для того чтобы проверить, является ли конструкция уточнением, зададим вопрос "где именно?"  к основному обстоятельству места:

"Он завернул (куда?) куда-то вбок, (**куда именно?**) в мощёный переулок".